# Express mongoDB Integration testing for private/secured routes

Tags: mongodb, express, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to run a integration test for one of the express routes in the application.

The routed is a protected route allows user to create supplier when user is authenticated.

I am trying to login user before making a request to the 'api/v1/supplier' (protected route) route but not able to login user before calling the Login API give 500 error back, the Login API is working as expected when tested separately.

Here is the test that I am trying. request help!

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

const expect = require('chai').expect;
const request = require('supertest');

const app = require('../../../app.js');
const conn = require('../../../db/index.js');

describe('POST /api/v1/supplier ', () => {
  let token = '';

  before(done => {
    conn
      .connect()
      .then(done())
      .catch(err => done(err));
  });

  after(done => {
    conn
      .close()
      .then(done())
      .catch(err => done(err));
  });

  it('Error, on unauthorized POST Supplier request', done => {
    request(app)
      .post('/api/v1/users/login')
      .send({ email: 'sgrmhdk00@gmail.com', password: '12345678' })
      .end(function(err, res) {
        token = res.body.token;
      });

    request(app)
      .post('/api/v1/supplier')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + token)
      .send({ supplierID: '1234567' })
      .then(res => {
        const body = res.body;
        expect(body).to.contain.property('status');
        expect(body).to.contain.property('error');
        done();
      })
      .catch(err => done(err));
  });
});
```

db/index.js

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const DB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp';

function connect() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });
    const setDatabase = () => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        const DB = process.env.DATABASE;
        return DB;
      } else {
        const DB = process.env.DATABASE_PRODUCTION.replace(
          '<PASSWORD>',
          process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
        );
        return DB;
      }
    };

    const DB = setDatabase();

    mongoose
      .connect(DB, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
      })
      .then(() => console.log('DB connection successful!'));
  });
}

function close() {
  return mongoose.disconnect();
}

module.exports = { connect, close };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call you API with token, but the two calls are asynchronous, you need call the second method inside  the end of the first:

```
 it('Error, on unauthorized POST Supplier request', done => {
    request(app)
      .post('/api/v1/users/login')
      .send({ email: 'sgrmhdk00@gmail.com', password: '12345678' })
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if(err){
          done(err)
          return
        }

        token = res.body.token;

        request(app)
         .post('/api/v1/supplier')
         .set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + token)
         .send({ supplierID: '1234567' })
         .then(res => {
          const body = res.body;
          expect(body).to.contain.property('status');
          expect(body).to.contain.property('error');
          done();
        })
        .catch(err => done(err));
      });

    
  });
```

Comment: Hi.No luck..api call to login user fails

Comment: verify that env vars are loading correctly, because dotenv get .env file from root of start file